# VS Code Haskell extension - Couldn't figure out what GHC version the project is using

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, haskell-stack

When I open some haskell project in VS Code I get this message:

*Couldn't figure out what GHC version the project is using:
/home/andrej/.config/Code - OSS/User/globalStorage/haskell.haskell/haskell-language-server-wrapper-1.2.0-linux --project-ghc-version exited with exit code 1:
No 'hie.yaml' found. Try to discover the project type!
Failed get project GHC version, since we have a none cradle*

How to solve it?

Edit:

Here is tree structure of the project:

```
.
├── .exercism
│   └── metadata.json
├── package.yaml
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── ResistorColors.hs
├── stack.yaml
└── test
    └── Tests.hs
```

Comment: Seems like you need to create that `hie.yaml`.

Comment: hi, could you share the output of calling `/path/to/haskell-language-server-wrapper-1.2.0-linux --probe-tools` and the same command with `--project-ghc-version` in a shell with the current working dir in the project root dir?

Comment: https://github.com/Avi-D-coder/implicit-hie#readme You can use this tool to generate an `hie.yaml` file.

Comment: when i run `stack build` and then restart vs code, error no longer appears

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your project has stack project config files, The Haskell extension should be able to figure out what it needs and a `hie.yaml` file to configure the extension is typically not needed for simple projects like this.

`haskell-language-server`, the project upon which the VS Code Haskell exension is based, is still under active development and often gets a bit stuck. The folllowing can help sort a lot of common issues:

1. Run

   ```
   stack clean
   stack build
   ```
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+P and click 'Haskell: Restart Haskell LSP Server' (start typing to find it).

Happy Haskelling!

Comment: 'Haskell: Restart Haskell LSP Server' doesn't help. I still need to restart the VS code.

Comment: Then 'Reload Window' from the same dropdown should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

None of them working, until I delete `/Users/sweirich/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.10.4/environments/default`

Once you delete the default, and reopen the vs code. VS Haskell extension will reset the setting, and the error seems to go away.

Found the answer at https://issueexplorer.com/issue/haskell/haskell-language-server/2224

Comment: Also worked when I had similar issue to this: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/2495 - seems deleting `default` can "fix" a bunch of seemingly unrelated issues.